# How to view file contents as it was in a commit - Like `git show`

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Briefly: What's the SourceTree equivalent of:

`git show 946a759:File.h`

---

More thorougly:

1. File.h *did not change* in commit 946a759, I just want to see the contents of the file as it was at the time of that commit.
2. I do know that I *could* change the Log View - Working Copy view to show *all* of my files, find the file in the list, right-click on it and choose "Log Selected", find the commit (or the next oldest one) but

   - That's a cumbersome process
   - I don't want to change the Log View's setup to show all files
   - It's really difficult to find a random file in that huge long list of files.

---

So what I'd like to do is be in the Log View with my master branch selected in the left sidebar, find the particular commit in the tree, and then do the equivalent of git show rev:AnyFileIWant. I'd be just fine typing in the path to the file.

I can't seem to find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlassian has said this is not possible.

> I don't think we have something similar available on sourcetree. However, you can select the given file in a commit and from the contextual menu click on "Log Selected" to see all the various modifications of that given file. Thought this doesn't exactly do the same as what you need, if you have an idea of the date of modification, you can figure out which version to look at.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/Equivalent-of-a-git-show-on-a-specific-commit/qaq-p/715867

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in SourceTree, however your IDE might be able to do it:

## IntelliJ IDEA (and other JetBrains IDEs with integrated VCS)

Right-click your commit in the VCS view (*alt + 9*) and select *Show Repository at Revision*.

[image: Show Repository at Revision]

A repositories view will pop up right where your project view was. You can now open any file at the time of the revision / commit. Files are read-only.

[image: Repositories view]